# Error; (array) speelVeld is not defined

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I need to make a tile based game for a project on my school and ran into a "critical" error that I can't seem to solve.

This is my script:

```
function init(){
var speelVeldBreedte;
var speelVeldHoogte;
var speelVeld = [
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1]
];

var speelTerrein = document.getElementById("speelterrein");
}

speelVeldBreedte=speelVeld[0].length; 
speelVeldHoogte=speelVeld.length;

var schaalTerrein = 20;
speelTerrein.width = speelVeldBreedte * schaalTerrein; 
speelTerrein.height = speelVeldHoogte * schaalTerrein;


var ctx = speelTerrein.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,speelTerrein.width,speelTerrein.height);
    for (var y=0; y<speelVeldHoogte;y++){
        for (var x=0;x<speelVeldBreedte;x++){
            var steen = speelVeld[y][x];
            if (steen> 01){
                ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(100,0,0)";
                ctx.fillRect(x*schaalTerrein,y*schaalTerrein,schaalTerrein,schaalTerrein);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
uncaughtReferenceError: speelVeld is not defined.
```

which refers to line 32 which is:

```
speelVeldBreedte=speelVeld[0].length;
```

I hope someone could tell me how to solve this error and what exactly the problem is.

Thanks in advance,
Remy

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `speelVeld` in the body of the `init()` function, and your call on line 32 is outside of that function -- hence, JS cannot "see" the variable because it is out of scope.

Comment: So let's say I were to put all of the code inside the init function, and then load it using window.load = init;, it would work?

Comment: You should at least declare the variables outside of init()... and, indeed, make sure init() gets called. But you wouldn't put your entire game into a single function, would you?

Comment: well the problem when I put the code outside the function is that it tells me at this line:

speelTerrein.width = speelVeldBreedte * schaalTerrein;

That I get the error: uncaught TypeError: cannot set property 'width' of null

Comment: That means your line `var speelTerrein = document.getElementById("speelterrein");` has produced a null -- in other words, there is no page element called `speelterrein`.

Comment: but inside the html5 file I made a div with the id "speelterrein", and when I type 'document.getElementById(' it automatically shows the reference to speelterrein.

That's why I'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

spelVeld (and all variables for that matter) is scoped inside the init() function.

You can read about scope here : http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/